# How do i use GET correctly in php?

Tags: php, html, sql

i tried to find a solution for my problem for 2 hours now, but i don't know why my code does not work.

I have a sql output which looks like this:

```
function output(){
    while($row = $this->statement->fetch()) {
        $id = $row["id"];
        echo '
            <tr>
                <td>'.$row["comname"].'</td>
                <td>'.$row["district"].'</td>
                <td>'.$row["industry"].'</td>
                <td>"<a href="?details=' . $id . '">Details</a>"</td>
            </tr> 
            <br>
            ';
    }
```

If someone click on the link "Details" i want to give out more information about that specific company. Therefore i save the id in the url to identify which company was clicked.
To check if the Details link was clicked, i wrote this:

Edit: just added the "$id = $_GET['details']" after your hints, it looks like this now:

```
    if (isset($_GET['details'])){
        $id = $_GET['details'];
        echo $id;
    }
}
```

When i click on the link "Details" it changes the URL correctly, but it doesn't print the id. (I don't only want to print the id, i just do this to check the functionality.) Why does my code not work? Is there a second "$GET" i have to use? I really don't know what is going on.

Edit: The php-code ends here, there is nothing i do afterwards.

Edit2: I tried  `print_r($_GET)` and it looks like, the id is not even in the $GET-Array. Also the `if (isset($_GET['details']))` statement is not executed.

Thank you!

Comment: try a `print_r($_GET);` to check what is being placed in the GET Array

Comment: Add [error reporting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/845021/) to the
top of your file(s) _while testing_ right after your opening PHP tag for example. 
Even if you are developing on a server configured as LIVE you will now see any errors. 
`<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: To get errors out of PHP even in a LIVE environment add these 4 lines to the top of any `MYSQLI_` based script you want to debug 
`ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('log_errors',1); error_reporting(E_ALL); mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);`. 
This will force any `MYSQLI_` errors to generate an Exception that you can see on the browser as well as normal PHP errors.

Comment: You've changed your code without any comments. First you had `echo $id;` without `$id = $_GET['details'];` which make sense that it didn't work. Now you've added `$id = $_GET['details'];` without _any_ explanation or comment. How in the world are we suppose to be able to help if we have _no clue_ what your actual code is and what the result of it is? Did you try it? Did it work?

Comment: Also show us what else is coded in the script after the code you show. That may be having some effect on why you dont see any output

Comment: Sorry @MagnusEriksson i am completely new here.
I am going to comment my edit right away. Sorry!

Comment: @RiggsFolly Thank you so much for your help and hints! The php-code ends after that. I don't do anything after the print. 
But your hint with printing out the GET array helped me to understand the problem. The id is not placed in the GET array, so i know at least why printing does not work. Do you know what i have to do to get the id in in the GET array?

Comment: If that is all the code, then what is the second `}` doing there.

Comment: As this would appear to be a different file to the one that created the web page with the link on it then you need to add the script file name to the link `<a href="script_file_name.php?details=' . $id . '">`

Comment: The second } just closes a class.
Edit: My file has a lot of code (there is a html form above and stuff...), but these statements i post here, are at the end from the php-code. It is all in one file...

Answer (score 1):

You should print the `$_GET['details']`:

```
if (isset($_GET['details'])){
    echo $_GET['details'];
}
```

Or put it in a variable:

```
if (isset($_GET['details'])){
    $id = $_GET['details'];
    echo $id;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I tried that, but it doesn't work. There is no error or something, just nothing happens.

Answer (score 1):

[`$_GET[]`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php) is just an array of all GET parameters in the URL. You see them for example on https://www.google.com?q=stack+overflow where the parameter `q` is set to `stack+overflow`. So if you would echo out `$_GET["q"]` on that URL you would get `stack+overflow`. You can store it in a variable like $id and echo it out, but you need to set it first like `$id = $_GET["details"];`

EDIT: I just realized the code you have now is vulnerable to an attack called [XSS](https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/xss/) or HTML Injection. Since we can specify the `$_GET["details"]` and so `$id` that is being echoed, an attacker can put HTML code or the `<script>` tag in there to execute dangerous JavaScript code on everyone that accesses the URL.

Luckily, there is an easy fix: just put the function `htmlspecialchars()` around whatever user input you `echo`. The `echo` you have here would become `echo htmlspecialchars($id);`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. 
I tried that (also just added this to the code in the question now) but it still doesn't work. No error message, just nothing happens at all.

Comment: The code you provided works fine for me, are you sure that 1. the URL looks something like `site.com/page.php?details=42` and 2. that the id isn't being printed? Try to look at the source code (Ctrl + U) and search (Ctrl + F) for the number you specified

Comment: I also just realized your code is vulnerable to an XSS attack. Look at the EDIT in my answer

Comment: I checked that, hoping that the print just hides somewhere, but nothing. The URL works, it looks exactly like you wrote it... But it seems like the $GET Array doesn't receive the id... 
Idk if thats necessary to tell, but above the php-code i wrote a html form, and the $GET array just contains values from this form, but not the id from the php-code.

Comment: Lets found out where the problem lies. Could you try just printing something fixed as `echo "42"` instead of $id. If this works we know it has something to do with the $id variable not being set

Comment: Yes thank you! I tried that, also nothing. 
Also, i printed the $Get Array to check if the id is in there, but it's not. So the condition must be false. 
I really don't know what i have to do to get the id in the $GET-Array...